# Non-nullable variable 'newTextTitle' must be assigned before it can be used

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   String newTextTitle;
    return Container(
          child: Center(
            TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              autofocus: true,
              onChanged: (String newText){
                newTextTitle = newText;
                },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onPressed: (){
                addTask(newTextTitle);
              },
```

1. I tried with "late" but did not work.
2. I initialized "newTextTitle" in the TextField.

Comment: There are some wrong syntax in sample code, The Container has a two child and Center does not have a child....

Answer (score 0):

Add question mark to String, Refer null-Safty [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety) and [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

```
 String? newTextTitle;
```

Your Widget:

```
     TextField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          autofocus: true,
          onChanged: (String newText){
            newTextTitle = newText;
            },
        ),
```